# How to style easypiechart using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, counter, pie-chart

I wanna to create a counter circle like below, i use [easy-pie-chart](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/) but i haven't any idea on how to style created circles like as below. Is there a way to style them using css and make their look like as below?

Any resources or articles comes helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
div {
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #EC5F51;
    border: 2px solid #EC5F51;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position:relative;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, #ccc 50%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%);
}
div:before{
    content: "pure CSS3";
    position: absolute;
    width: 114px;
    height: 114px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 18px;
    top: 18px;
    line-height:114px;
    text-align:center
}

Markup:
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this (or something very close to this) can *technically* be done by just using pure CSS.

What you are looking for is something relatively new called *animations*.

Let's define some markup to work with. Nothing fancy, just:

```
<div id="wheel"></div>
```

And, let's give it some CSS:

```
#wheel {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #90F090;
    border-right: 5px solid #000070;
}
```

Since this deals with animation, I won't post every picture along the way, but here's what it looks like:

[image: Border Circle]

This looks close to what you're looking for, and with some manipulation, you can get it looking nice, but I'm assuming you want it to *animate* to the correct percentage.

For demonstration, add a `:hover` effect to it to rotate it:

```
#wheel:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(80deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(80deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(80deg);
    transform: rotate(80deg);
}
```

```css
#wheel {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #90F090;
  border-right: 5px solid #000070;
}
#wheel:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(80deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(80deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(80deg);
  transform: rotate(80deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="wheel">
```

But, you want it to *animate* on its own. As of CSS3, there is a way to do that! It's called **animate**.

Anyways, the general syntax is [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp):

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation: <name> <duration> <direction> <delay> <count> <timing function>; 

/* Standard syntax */
animation: <name> <duration> <direction> <delay> <count> <timing function>;
```

- <name> = Some name you give it.
- <duration> = How long it lasts.
- [<direction>](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-direction.asp) = Which direction (normal/reverser/alternate)
- <delay> = How long after loading until it starts.
- <count> = How many times to do it (or infinite).
- [<timing function>](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp) = Specifies the speed as the animation goes.

Phew. That's a lot. Actually, ***now we're ready to start***.

After getting all of that figured out, it's time to create the animation.

The syntax for that is as follows:

```
/* "Standard" way */
@keyframes <name> { 
    from {
        /* After <duration>, play the animation FROM this state */
     } 
     to {
        /* Until it gets TO this state within <duration>'s time */
        /* Unless <direction> is reverse/alternate */
     }
     /* Then repeat <count> times. */
}

/* Engine specific implementations */
@-webkit-keyframes <name>
@-moz-keyframes <name>
@-ms-keyframes <name>
@-o-keyframes <name>
```

Also, instead of from/to, you can use [percentages](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) (5% through animation, be here. 25% through, be here, etc.). In fact, from just means 0%, and to means 100%.

Now, stick the rotate from 0deg to 359deg (not 360, because 360deg = 0deg, it wouldn't move) inside the "from" and "to", and you have yourself a spinning wheel.

```css
#wheel {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #90F090;
    border-right: 5px solid #000070;
    
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation: spin 5s linear 2s infinite normal; 
    
    /* Standard syntax */
    animation: spin 5s linear 2s infinite normal; 
} 


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
     } to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
     }
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
     } to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
     }
}
```

```html
<div id="wheel"></div>
```

**Here's the problem**. Remember when I said you can *technically* achieve this effect with pure CSS?

Well, we are using a different color border to simulate the thing moving (your "loading" bar, or "pie" chart value). In a *circle*, each border takes up *exactly* 25% of it... This means that you can only animate 90 degrees worth of an arc at any one time.

**The solution?** Overlap two circles, have one "hide" the desired amount by rotating it ever so slightly.

```css
#container {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation: spin 5s linear 2s infinite normal; 
    
    /* Standard syntax */
    animation: spin 5s linear 2s infinite normal; 
}

#wheel, #hide {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #90F090;
    border-right: 5px solid #000070;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
} 

#hide {
    border-color: #90F090;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    z-index: 11;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
     } to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
     }
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
     } to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
     }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="hide"></div>
    <div id="wheel"></div>
</div>
```

[(Here)](http://jsfiddle.net/nykg9qt7/) is a fiddle showing a smaller amount rotating.

Using combinations of transparent borders/overlapping (or, like Tambo answered with, background-gradients), you can easily achieve any arc length you want.

To have a loading circle, you can play around with animate a bit until you get exactly what you want working.

However, the pie chart library you're using handles the job nicely by itself. :)

**Note:** The purpose of all of this was to show you animations and circles using pure CSS. The rest you can learn from and tweak to your liking.

Comment: Thanks Mr Jefferson for explanation. I choose Tambo's way for simplicty. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I used the following pie chart.. It was simple to use.. Just needs a few modifications to dynamically update your percentage value. The bar color and size can be adjusted too. Take a look at the documentation.

http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/

```js
var chartColors = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'red'];

$('.easy-pie-chart .number').each(function(i, e) {
      var val = Math.round(yourValues);
      var chart = $(yourElement).data('easyPieChart');
      $(yourElement).children('span').text(val);
      $(yourElement).attr('data-percent', val); //add a class attribute in markup
      if (!chart) {
        $(e).easyPieChart({
            animate: 1000, //animation time
            size: 75,
            lineWidth: 3,
            barColor: App.getLayoutColorCode(chartColors[i]),
            //and a few more useful properties you'll find that I haven't used
          }                  
      else {
         chart.update(val);
      }
 });
```

And finally, you might find this one useful too:

http://codepen.io/rendro/pen/vrezp